# React Masonry Layout has bugs rendering images with fade-in effect

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby

Code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-ry8sm

You can try demo: https://ry8sm.sse.codesandbox.io/

Every picture is an `Enlarger` component which will zoom in when you click on it. And they are designed to show up sequentially by fading in. I use `Ref` to track every `Enlarger` and here is the code snippet for it.

```
import Img from "react-image-enlarger"

class Enlarger extends React.Component {
  state = { zoomed: false, opacity: 0 }

  toggleOpacity = o => {
    this.setState({ opacity: o })
  }

  render() {
    const { index, orderIndex, src, enlargedSrc, onLoad } = this.props
    return (
      <div style={{ margin: "0.25rem" }} onLoad={onLoad}>
        <Img
          style={{
            opacity: this.state.opacity,
            transition: "opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25,0.46,0.45,0.94)",
            transitionDelay: `${orderIndex * 0.07}s`,
          }}
          zoomed={this.state.zoomed}
          src={src}
          enlargedSrc={enlargedSrc}
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ zoomed: true })
          }}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            this.setState({ zoomed: false })
          }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Enlarger
```

And I have a Masonry component which will achieve the Masonry layout

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import imagesLoaded from "imagesloaded"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import TransitionGroup from "react-transition-group/TransitionGroup"

class MasonryGrid extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.onload = this.resizeAllGridItems()
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeAllGridItems)

    let allItems = document.getElementsByClassName("masonry-grid--item")
    for (let x = 0; x < allItems.length; x++) {
      imagesLoaded(allItems[x], this.resizeInstance)
    }
  }

  resizeAllGridItems = () => {
    let allItems = document.getElementsByClassName("masonry-grid--item")
    for (let x = 0; x < allItems.length; x++) {
      this.resizeGridItem(allItems[x])
    }
  }

  resizeGridItem = item => {
    let grid = document.getElementsByClassName("masonry-grid")[0]
    let rowHeight = parseInt(
      window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue("grid-auto-rows")
    )
    let rowGap = parseInt(
      window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue("grid-row-gap")
    )
    let rowSpan = Math.ceil(
      (item.querySelector(".content").getBoundingClientRect().height + rowGap) /
        (rowHeight + rowGap)
    )
    item.style.gridRowEnd = "span " + rowSpan
  }

  resizeInstance = instance => {
    let item = instance.elements[0]
    this.resizeGridItem(item)
  }

  render() {
    const MasonryGrid = {
      display: "grid",
      gridGap: `${this.props.gridGap}`,
      gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(${
        this.props.itemWidth
      }px, 1fr))`,
      gridAutoRows: "10px",
    }
    return (
      <TransitionGroup>
        <div className="masonry-grid" style={MasonryGrid}>
          {this.props.children.length >= 1 &&
            this.props.children.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <div className="masonry-grid--item" key={index}>
                  <div className="content">{item}</div>
                </div>
              )
            })}
        </div>
      </TransitionGroup>
    )
  }
}

MasonryGrid.defaultProps = {
  itemWidth: 250,
  gridGap: "6px 10px",
}

MasonryGrid.propTypes = {
  itemWidth: PropTypes.number,
  gridGap: PropTypes.string,
}

export default MasonryGrid
```

The problem is, if you look at the demo, when you click on tab `project1`, you will see the pictures show up on top of each other and doesn't spread well as intended. **But once you resize the browser a little bit,** they becomes normal and form the Masonry layout I wanted. I suspect it has something to do with the fade-in effect I implemented but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Have you asked about this on the repo's issues page?  That might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: @jmargolisvt which repo?

Comment: It seems you are having trouble with react-image-enlarger?  Fwiw, `getElementsByClassName` is not a very "react way" of doing things.  Maybe structuring your code to follow React's dynamic programming model will make it easier to achieve your desired effect in a manner that's easier to debug.